# Saving lots of dictionaries and arrays

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

My game comes with lots of .plist files containing many dictionaries, arrays, etc. They are about each party member's stats, info, etc.

A singleton is in charge of reading all those files and provide the necessary data for my game to run.

The game, at many points, will edit such values from the singleton, like a hero's level, stats, etc.

Eventually, the player will be given the option to "save" the game. My original idea was to basically tell the singleton to "overwrite" the .plist files within the project with the new edited data (the new data might have changes in stat entries etc, or even brand-new dictionaries representing new party members etc) and done.

But, I don't know how to do that, or even if it is possible.

I heard about NSUserDefaults, but I don't know if it suitable for what I am aiming, considering that the amount of dictionaries and arrays *will* be quite big, and that it is possible to keep adding up more dictionaries and arrays in the future. Imagine that the party can have as many members as you wish, for instance.

*Note: there are no multiple save files/profiles. When you press save, it saves, without asking anything else.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but we need some more info. Any code snippets to examine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults is not suitable for any substantial amount of data.  Just write the plist to the documents directory, specify `atomic:YES` to insure the entire file is written.

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

> If YES, the array (or dictionary) is written to an auxiliary file, and
>   then the auxiliary file is renamed to path. If NO, the array is
>   written directly to path. **The YES option guarantees that path, if it
>   exists at all, won’t be corrupted even if the system should crash
>   during writing.**

This method exists for both `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`,

Obtain the document directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
BOOL status = [NSDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

`NSDictionary` could have ten `NSArray` depending on the top element of the plist.

Consider using CoreData.

Comment: It seems more likely the openings poster wants to save all data from his Singleton to the filesystem, in which case he might want to implement the NSCoding protocol to save all arrays, dictionaries and other object data to the filesystem.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I considered that but was swayed by there being several plist structured as opposed to model classes containing the data.  But, yes, NSCoding is also a great solution and may well be the best solution for the OP.